# Acer seems to be dying

Tags: maple

We have had our Acer planted in the garden for about 10 years. This year it lost leaves and only one branch has come back.  What is wrong with it.

Comment: Impossible to say from so few details. I see one dying near me (apparently) because drainage was altered (ruined, really) making soil too wet for it.

Comment: Please share more details and a few closeup pictures .

Comment: If you know the species, please add it to your answer. Some species in my area are affected by a wilt - my own sugar maple died of it when it was about 15 years old. Also, please add where you live in the world.

Comment: You can [edit] the question to add more details and pictures.